# Как сначала проверять есть ли у поля required, а только потом переходить к JS?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть форма, если например input пустой чтобы было такое сообщение как на последнем скриншоте, если заполнен, чтобы срабатывал js код.

Comment: Событие submit у формы именно по такой логике и работает

Comment: Принтер потек, беда :(